# method chaining including class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, methods, chaining

I'm trying to implement method chaining in C++, which turns out to be quite easy if the constructor call of a class is a separate statement, e.g:

```
Foo foo;

foo.bar().baz();
```

But as soon as the constructor call becomes part of the method chain, the compiler complains about expecting ";" in place of "." immediately after the constructor call:

```
Foo foo().bar().baz();
```

I'm wondering now if this is actually possible in C++. Here is my test class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
    }

    Foo& bar()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    Foo& baz()
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I also found an example for "fluent interfaces" in C++ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.2B.2B) which seems to be exactly what I'm searching for. However, I get the same compiler error for that code.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention this: Visual Studio 2010 (Professional).

Comment: Foo foo = bar().baz().bang();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have forgotten the actual name for the `Foo` object. Try:

```
Foo foo = Foo().bar().baz();
```

Comment: Or you can save a (const) reference to the object rather than copying the temporary into a new variable.

Comment: @LokiAstari: unfortunately no, because baz returns a reference to a temporary, not a temporary. (Made the same mistake myself)

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
// creates a temporary object
// calls bar then baz.
Foo().bar().baz();
```

Comment: although in this case, returning a reference to a temporary object is a bit dodgy ;-)

Comment: No its well defined here. As the temporary object remains valid until the end of the statement (the ';'). All is fare in love and temporaries.