# C++ Method chaining on constructor

Tags: c++, method-chaining

I'm trying allow for method chaining on the Constructor and I have ran into the same problem on this [C++ method chaining including class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877175/c-method-chaining-including-class-constructor) and I have tried the suggested answers but still getting the same error. My code is below:

```
class Signal {

public:
    Signal() { }

    Signal& Emphasize() {

        return *this;
    }   

};
enum ReadType { NATIVE = 0, DOUBLE, };

class Wav : public Signal {

  public:

          Wav(string fileName, ReadType type) {

    }   

};
```

I have tried calling from the following:

```
Wav* wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE).Emphasize();
```

And:

```
Wav wave = Wav("asf", DOUBLE).Emphasize();
```

I don't know whether the actual process is possible since "Emphasize" it's not a constructor but hopefully I will be allowed to access it. What could I be doing wrong here for this not to work?

Hope someone can help :)

UPDATE:

I put "Emphasize()" as a class member inside "Wav" and it worked, how I wanted. BUT does anyone know of a way I can access this member inside "Signal" without having to place the class member inside of "Wav"?

UPDATE:

```
class Signal {

public:
    Signal() { }

    Signal* Emphasize() {
        return this;
    }
 };
 enum ReadType {

        NATIVE = 0, DOUBLE,
    };

 class Wav : public Signal {

   public:
      Wav(string fileName, ReadType type) {

       }    
 };

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  Wav* wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE)->Emphasize();
 }
```

Comment: Hint: `new` expression returns a pointer.

Comment: For what (I think) you're trying to achive, the [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html) might be better suited.

Comment: So you answered it yourself then, cause the solution in the update is what I would have proposed. Issue is that you cannot do method chaining that works for heap and stack allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new` expression returns a pointer so you just have to do :

```
Wav* wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE)->Emphasize();
//                                ^^
```

Also your method `Emphasize` return a reference on a Signal object :

```
Signal& Emphasize() {
//    ^ Reference
    return *this;
}
```

But you are trying to assign this reference to a pointer `Wav*`.

You have two choices here :

```
// ...
Signal* Emphasize() {
    return this;
}

// ...
Wav* wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE)->Emphasize();
```

Or you keep you initiale `Emphasize` method :

```
// ...
Signal& Emphasize() {
    return *this;
}

// ...
Wav wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE)->Emphasize();
```

---

**EDIT :**
Ok the real error is that you are trying to convert a `Signal` object into `Wav` object.

There is no convertion from `Signal` to `Wav` object.

**A Wav is a Signal but a Signal is not a Wav.**

You can do something like :

Inside your `Signal` class :

```
virtual Signal& Emphasize()=0;
```

And inside your `Wav` class :

```
Wav& Emphasize()
{
     return *this;
}
```

**OR**

```
Signal w = new Wav( "asf", DOUBLE )->Emphasize();
```

Comment: Would he also have to change `Emphasize()` to return a pointer?

Comment: @Pierre Fourgeaud Got the following error: `error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        Wav* wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE)->Emphasize();`

Comment: @Phorce I updated my answer. Another question : Did you included the class definition correctly in the file where you are doing : `Wav* wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE)->Emphasize();` ?

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud Hey, I tried your suggested improvement but it did not work. I just seem to be getting: `error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        Wav* wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE)->Emphasize();
                                          ^` Updated the code in my original post to show what I'm currently doing

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud Just seen your last edit. Should I therefore have the method "Emphasize()" in wav that just calls "Signal::Emphasize()"? That seems like the only possible solution

Comment: @Phorce Look at my edit, there is an explanation for this error.

Comment: @Phorce The last solutions can be a `cast` but I'm not sure it is a good solution...

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Wav* wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE);
Signal x = wave->Emphasize();
```

Or if you want Wav object at the end, you can define Emphasize() virtually at Signal class

```
virtual Signal& Emphasize()=0;
```

Then at Wav class you can define

```
Wav& Emphasize(){

    return *this;
}
```

In the main you can call

```
Wav* wave = new Wav("asf", DOUBLE);
Wav w = wave->Emphasize();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, no, I'm looking to allow for method chaining.

Comment: Ok, your problem is that Emphasize returns pointer to the Signal object, maybe doing it virtually helps you.